# What types of design patterns make events easier?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm working on a game and I'm finding myself having a ton of listeners.

For example, when the language of the game changes, the LanguageManager sends a languageChanged event which causes all interested gui elements to get the new text and redraw themselves. This means every interested gui element implements the LanguageListener class.

Another thing I find myself doing a lot is injecting dependencies. The GuiFactory needs to set fonts so it has a pointer to the FontManager (which holds an array of TTF fonts), it also has a GuiSkinManager so it can get Image* based on the skin of the game. Is this the right way to do this?

My main concern however is with the listeners and the massive amount of them; especially for the gui. The gui library im using is almost entirely listener driven. I can get away with ActionListeners most of the time but I still have nested ifs for if event.getSource() == button2 etc.

In general what type of design patterns are used to avoid these issues in large game projects that are much more complex than mine?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're aware of the Observer pattern (Ihttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which is basically the model for Listeners. What I don't understand is why you have nested ifs - surely you should only bind observers to the observables they are interested in (or listen to things the listener cares about)? i.e. Button2Handler listens to button2 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners are often used in huge applications as well. Don't be scared of them. I'm working with one of the biggest java app and I have seen tones of different listeners there, so it looks like that's the way to be.

For smaller applications `Mediator` could be way-around if you realy hate listening for events ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one interface per event type containing a single callback (ie. LanguageListener), if you were to follow the Observer design pattern, you would have one interface xObserver with a callback for every kind of event.

```
class GuiElementObserver
{
public:
    void LanguageChangedEvent(...) {}
    void OtherEvent() {}
};
```

The default empty implementations allow you to redefine only the events you are interested in in the concrete classes.

Concerning dependencies, whenever I refactor code, I like to use the Single Responsibility Principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You said that the GuiFactory needs to set fonts... But is it really the responsibility of a factory to set fonts?

If you limit the responsibilities of your classes to what they were originally meant to do, you should have leaner classes, cleaner code and fewer dependencies. In this case, maybe adding a font manager and moving the font related code there could be a solution.